# Doze mode on Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-doze

I am facing issue in my app regarding doze mode. I am making a chat application and when app is in backgroud during doze mode and receive any message . Device does not show notification in orea.

I have followed the proper procedure for OREO notification by building channel for it.

I need to find if there is a way to whiteList my app from doze mode so that I can have notifications. Or any other process to optimize notification building.

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 0):

I do not need to whitelist my application to get notifications in doze mode. I recommend to look at your notification to see if you can find the issue there.

Some tips:

1. Send a notification, use the notification field. If theres no notification field it will be handled as a data notification. Data notifications are delivered when the app starts again.
2. Set priority to high.
3. Maybe use time to live = 0. That will make firebase to try harder to get it delivered. But it will be lost if it fails.

Hard to give you more direct advice when I do not know where you are sending the notification from.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages

Comment: you talk about FCM but OP doesn't mention anything about it

Comment: Actually I am receiving "HIGH PRIORITY" data fcm in doze mode but when I build the notification depending on the data in fcm. It doesn't not show.. I have used NotificationChannel ... Notification build perfectly fine when not in doze mode.